# Bootstrap website allowing small horizontal scroll on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My website is responsive but on mobile it allows me to pull it slightly to the left, ive tried all the view point metas i could find online and nothings working. On inspection there is nothing overlapping the screen so i cant see why it is showing this whitespace.

Here is the page in inspector view with the html tag selected

[image]

Im currently using

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale = 1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no" />
```

Comment: Try adding body { overflow: hidden; } to your css

Comment: You have some element that is too big to fit in the viewport. Eventually you can use `overflow-x: hidden` on the `body` element :)

Comment: Tell me that isn't the behavior of the emulator device on the google chrome tools ... there you can scroll a little like a bounce effect even if there is no content overflowing the page.

Comment: No ivegot it up onmy mobile aswell, the other side is finebut the right side there is still a gap

Comment: XD ok just to make sure, can you link up to your site or include enough code to replicate the issue ? maybe on codepen or jsfiddle

Comment: The silmple solution is to make sure the body has {overflow-x: hidden} and I would probably also make it position:relative. You may have an element somewhere that has a set width that is going beyond the framework.

Comment: @GazSmith can you post some code ? or a fiddle ?

Comment: I think you arent using <div class="container"> or <div class="container-fluid">